# Ruby: dealing with booleans: How to address not using military time for a clock Class

Tags: boolean

## TDD

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.2'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/pride'
require_relative 'clock'

class ClockTest < Minitest::Test
 def test_start_at_6
  clock = Clock.new
  
  assert_equal 6, clock.time
 end

 def test_passage_of_time

  clock = Clock.new
  clock.wait
  
  assert_equal 7, clock.time

  3.times { clock.wait }
  
  assert_equal 10, clock.time
 end

 def test_clocks_are_not_military_time

  clock = Clock.new
  8.times { clock.wait }
  
  assert_equal 2, clock.time
 end
end
```

## CODE

```
class Clock
 attr_reader :time

 def initialize
  @time = 6
 end

 def wait(time = 1)
  @time += time
 end

 def not_military_time
  @time += (time - 10)
 end
end
```

Can anyone guide me into figuring out how to address that the clocks are not in military time? It's coming as Expected : 2 , Actual : 14. I feel like there needs to be some of subtraction going in order to address the clock saying 2 instead of 14.

I know what I have in the code does not work, but am I on the right track?

Comment: In the twelve hour clock think what the next hour should be when you add an hour to 12 noon.

Comment: It should go to 1pm, but how to address that in code. Hm. I'll try to mess with it for a bit and see what i can come up with.

Comment: def not_military_time
     1.upto(12) + time
    end

Comment: is something like this make sense in this instance at all?

Comment: If you look through the tests and the code in your `Clock` class then nothing is ever calling your `not_military_time` method. This means there is no way for that method to affect anything. If you look at the tests they only interact with your clock by calling `wait` and then by checking the time using your `attr_reader` for `@time` so those are the places where you are able to change the behaviour in order to make the tests pass. Does that help?

Comment: i think? so i changed it to def standard_time @time += (wait - 12), or something?

Comment: Adding a `standard_time` method and making no other changes wouldn't help for the same reason I mentioned above - the method is never used so can't change the outcome.

Comment: @time + wait <= 12? Kind of tossing things out there but would I need to use a case statement or if/then

Comment: I've posted an answer with some pointers in the right direction. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you look through all of the tests you'll see that apart from `test_start_at_6` each test essentially calls `wait` some number of times and then checks for the right time in `clock.time`.

If you look at your code, `clock.time` is generated by `attr_reader` and so all it will ever do is return the current value of `@time`. So this leaves you with `wait` as a place to implement the behaviour needed to make the tests pass.

One other thing to notice is that you're currently overcomplicating the `wait` method. It's never called with any parameters and so the `time` parameter isn't needed. So to start simplify that to just:

```
def wait
  @time += 1
end
```

Next, step away from the code and make a little list showing for each *current* time what the *next* time needs to be after `wait` is called. You can then think about how to change `wait` so that it matches that required behaviour.

In terms of whether to use an `if` or a `case` statement, everything that you could achieve using a `case` statement can also be done with an `if` as an alternative. It's best to think about the most common use of a `case` statement which is for checking the same variable for various possible values. i.e. the `case` statement

```
case @time
when 1
  puts "One o'clock"
when 2
  puts "Two o'clock"
else
  puts "Later!"
end
```

is the same as:

```
if @time == 1
  puts "One o'clock"
elsif @time == 2
  puts "Two o'clock"
else
  puts "Later!"
end
```

Often when you're just working out what some logic needs to be you'll write it as an `if` statement and then once it's working realise that it can more elegantly be expressed as a `case` statement. In this exercise an `if` should be fine.

Comment: Ah, I can see where you're going with this, but I am still not sure how to assign 13 = 1 and have it do that for the whole time and reset again. def not_military_time
    @time.wait do |int|
      @time.upto(1..12)
    end

Comment: I am still not sure how to approach this, I know the method I wrote is wrong but I feel like it can be something to do with enums?

Comment: Also, I think I don't need def not_military_time, I can make the test pass from the wait method I believe? Throw in if/then statement there?

Comment: That's correct. Just needs an `if` condition in `wait`. No extra methods needed and no use of `upto` needed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still pretty lost, if @time == 13 then puts 1, is that sort of in the ballpark?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested with making a list showing for each current time what the next time needs to be after `wait` is called? Think through a couple of examples. e.g. `@time` is 6, `wait` is called, currently `wait` adds 1 to time (`@time = @time + 1`) so now `@time` is 7 (the correct answer). But when `@time` is 12 and `wait` adds 1 to `@time` it becomes 13 (the wrong answer) so what does `wait` need to do `@time` instead? Why do you think a `puts` is needed here? How would that help?

Comment: there is no need for a puts, I am just throwing things out there. Something like (at)time = (at)time += 1 unless @time >= 13 then somehow go back to 1?

Comment: I'd really try to stick to the basics until you've got these more clear in your head. So don't worry about the version of `if`/`unless` where the condition goes at the end of the line. Don't worry about using `+=` instead of just plain `=`. Just try to think about the most straightforward `if [condition] [thing that should happen] else [what should happen instead?] end`. Have a think what the condition should be (it's not _quite_ when `@time >= 13`) and have a think what should happen instead when that condition isn't true.